# Javascript Resize Images on shuffle

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I have some bootstrap thumbnails set up with a script that shuffles the images inside the thumbnails or `a` element inside the `li` That parts works fine except some images are larger/smaller than others. I would like for the images to resize on shuffle to match the space allowed in the `<li class="span#">` Is this possible in javascript with the function that I have?

Bootstrap Thumbnails:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" id="list">
                        <li class="span4">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/360x270" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span2">
                          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script> window.onload = function()
                {
                   $('ul#list li img').shuffle();
                };
         </script>

        <script>
        (function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);

    };

})(jQuery);
        </script>
```

The `span#` looks like this in css:

```
 .span4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.span3 {
  width: 220px;
}

.span2 {
  width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of shuffling the img elements, can you shuffle the li elements like this:

```
$('ul#list li').shuffle();
```

?

I created a fiddle with your code and it seems to work fine: [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Ump5R/)

If you can't do that, another option is to add the span classes directly to your img elements.

Comment: I would love for the images to change but have the elements or spans stay in the same place.

Comment: Is there a way to do that? That is what I'm trying to get to.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Basically find the nearest li and use its width / height:

```
$.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){

            // find nearest li and use its width / height
            var li = $(this).closest('li');
            var height = li.height();
            var width = li.width();
            $(this).height(height);
            $(this).width(width);

            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);

    };
```

Comment: They are still adjusting to the images size. Take a look: www.green-panda.com/website/panda/homepage.php (scroll to bottom)